# CMake - How to cross-platform link to the library generated by ExternalProject_Add?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake

My project depends on a CMake-based library, included as an external project with `ExternalProject_Add`, like so:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    mylibrary
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/my/library/source
    INSTALL_COMMAND "")
```

I then obtain the `BINARY_DIR` and `SOURCE_DIR` properties and pass them to the final target for inclusion/linking:

```
ExternalProject_Get_Property(mylibrary BINARY_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(mylibrary SOURCE_DIR)

target_link_libraries(myproject PRIVATE ${BINARY_DIR}/libmylibrary${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
target_include_directories(myproject PRIVATE ${SOURCE_DIR})
```

The problem: `BINARY_DIR` seems to be wrong when compiling the whole project on XCode, while on Linux is OK. A debug print of such variable in macOS:

```
/Users/me/myproject/build/mylibrary-prefix/src/mylibrary-build
```

While the actual file resides in

```
/Users/me/myproject/build/mylibrary-prefix/src/mylibrary-build/Debug
```

This of course breaks the final linking stage, as the linker can't find the library to link against. I'm not sure if this is a CMake bug (unlikely) or an error in my configuration (likely): any pointers?

Comment: Unless the project very cares about that, a location of the created library could differs on different platforms (more precisely, on different generators). So it could be possible that a library is created under `${BINARY_DIR}/` with "Unix Makefiles" generators and under `${BINARY_DIR}/<CONFIG>/` with XCode. You may check generator by inspecting [CMAKE_GENERATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html) variable and correct library path accordingly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, so basically I have to rely on conditional code? I'd love to avoid that if possible...